# How to select certain rows of a data set in R to then use in a function?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, iris-dataset

I am trying to find the Mahalanobis Distance between the different species in the `iris` dataset in R. I was able to find the distance between `setosa` and `versicolor` by the following code:

```
library(HDMD)

#To get Mahalanobis distances between Setosa and Versicolor,
set.vers<-pairwise.mahalanobis(x=iris[1:100,1:4], grouping=iris[1:100,]$Species)
md= sqrt(set.vers$distance)
```

However, I am struggling to do the same for `setosa` and `virginica`. I am not sure how to select the first 50 rows and last 50 rows of the data set (i.e. not have any `versicolor` data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get all combinations of levels in `iris$Species` with `combn` and compute the Mahalanobis distances.

```
library(HDMD)

inx <- sapply(levels(iris$Species), function(l) which(iris$Species == l), simplify = FALSE)
inx <- combn(inx, 2, function(x) unlist(x), simplify = FALSE)
set.vers_all <- lapply(inx, function(i) {
  pairwise.mahalanobis(x = iris[i, 1:4], grouping = droplevels(iris$Species[i]))
})
set.vers_all
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic subsetting question. You want to subset based on `Species`, something along the lines of (not tested)

```
ss <- iris[iris$Species %in% c("Setosa", "Virginica"), ]
pairwise.mahalanobis(x = ss, grouping = ss$Species)
```

You can of course change the species pair you want to compare in many ways.

Comment: When I use that, is says that ss has 0 rows. the following error appears '[1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)'

Comment: @daisybeats The error comes from upper cases in `"Setosa"` and `"Virginica"`. Once corrected, in the second line it must be `x = ss[-5]` or `x = ss[1:4]`. And `grouping = droplevels(ss$Species)` would avoid the warning message.

Comment: @RuiBarradas you're right, calculating the distance on non-numeric Species column is a bit harder to do.